# Can I run Elixir (Laravel) task runner tasks from within Laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I have been looking at Laravel Elixir from the Laravel docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir. I understand that you install it via package.json which is the file used by npm which isn't part of Laravel's package management (composer.json), you then get a wrapper for gulp with some commands for doing build management for frontend scripts and css. If I wanted to then use Elixir as part of the Laravel stack, for example for images, what would I need to do?

Comment: Or to word differently is there ever a time when build scripts contain parts of code that are also executed at run time? For example in Ruby you can run a rake task at run time. Rake::Task['task_name'].invoke

Comment: I'm sure you're looking for [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues)